# Azure python ComputeManagementClient retrieve number of machines for virtual machine scale sets (per date)

Tags: python, azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to retrieve the number of machines for virtual machine scale sets in python

**Edit**:
something that I failed to mention is that I need this data per date

wanted result:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list the vm in Azure virtual machine scale sets in python application, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal and assign Contributor role to the sp

```
az login
#create sp and assign Contributor role at subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "your service principal name"
```

[image]

2. code

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

client_id = "sp appId"
secret = "sp password"
tenant = "sp tenant"
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = client_id,
        secret = secret,
        tenant = tenant
)

Subscription_Id = ''
compute_client =ComputeManagementClient(credentials,Subscription_Id)
resource_group_name='Networking-WebApp-AppGW-V1-E2ESSL'
virtual_machine_scale_set_name='VMSS'
result=compute_client.virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.list(resource_group_name,virtual_machine_scale_set_name)
num=0
for item in result:
     num+=1
     print(item.name)

print(f'the number of vm in the virtual machine scale sets is {num}')
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.operations.virtualmachinescalesetvmsoperations?view=azure-python#list-resource-group-name--virtual-machine-scale-set-name--filter-none--select-none--expand-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-).

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your answer
but I need this data filtered by dates

is it possible to have it as a historical - number of machines per date ?

Comment: @NadavSternn Could you please describre your issue in detail?

Comment: Your solution gives the number of machines for the virtual scale set for the time of the query - but I need it to be historical data - I need to know that for 1 given date there were 2 machines and for another date there were 4 machines

Comment: I added a table a description, Thanks

Comment: @NadavStern Regarding the issue, you can make  a schedule  task to get the information every day.

Comment: I can understand this solution but there is a problem with it - if the table I work with get truncated and I need this historical data - it will be an issue for me

Comment: @NadavStern you can store the data in Azure table storage. When you run a time, you can insert one record to azure table. For more details, please refer  to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-python

Comment: @NadavStern Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: yupp ... as I said before - I need to access historical data

Comment: @NadavStern As far as I knew, we may can get the information from azure activity log.